# Is possible to use manual refuel in Kerbal Space Program?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In **Kerbal Space Program**, career mode...I am trying to pass fuel from the Rober-bus to the spaceship. I have an engineer working on it and I am trying to attach that yellow external fuel duct to connect both.. so I could transfer fuel...
But seems is not possible (where you see the arrow I click on it, ast it is green, and cannot attach it...)

**So my questions are:**

- How can I attack that yellow fuel duct?
- Is there any other way of passing fuel from Rover to Spacechip?

[image]

Comment: Technically it seems to be possible: The mods "KIS" / "KAT" have special fuel lines and can connect two separate crafts together to transfer fuel. It is a mystery to me, why this is not possible in the "Some reassembly update" (version 1.11).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To transfer fuel you will have to dock your vessels. This can be done either using docking ports on both vessels or a "grabbing unit" aka the "claw" on one of them. You will also need to have at least one upgrade of the science facility back at the Kerbal Space Center to enable resource transfer.

Once your vessels are docked, right click the source and the destination tanks while holding Alt, and use the In/Out buttons to transfer fuel as needed.

If docking the two vessels is impractical, you can use a small rover or spaceship to move the fuel.

---

Regarding the yellow pipe, it can only link parts on the same vessel, so you cannot use it to transfer fuel between vessels. But with resource transfer, if the tanks are part of the same vessel, then the pipe is not needed. It's purpose is really only to allow engines to draw fuel from tanks from which they would not draw otherwise.

However if you would rather use a pipe to transfer fuel, and you are playing with mods, the Kerbal Attachment System mod does offer pipes to do this.